# Update IntelliJ default Gradle version

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, openjdk-17

When starting a new project I get the message unsupported JDK.  Using Gradle 7.1.  I want to update that default Gradle to 7.3-rc-1.

However, I just can't seem to find where to do this outside of a specific project. I am not sure where IntelliJ obtains it's Gradle version, and it has auto-updated in the past.

Sure I could update it afterwards, but as IntelliJ seems to break on trying to create folders and doesn't go back to do it once Gradle is updated. It would save a lot of headache for IntelliJ and myself to update or force it to use the version I want before the project creation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLyxF.png

Comment: At the moment 2021.2.2 version uses gradle 7.1 for new projects which does not support 17 JDK. As a workaround for now, one could create a new project with lower JDK version and then change the Gradle version to 7.2 in `<project dir>/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file and set 17 JDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ bundles version of Gradle much like it bundles a version of the JDK. In order to upgrade the bundled version of Gradle, you must update Intellij. However, there is no guarantee that an updated version of IntelliJ will come with an updated version of Gradle.

Comment: Thanks! I was racking my brain trying to update this. I just assumed it was more modular than it is.